# Salesforce REST Apex Class working in Workbench not cURL

Tags: rest-api, permissions

I’ve created an apex class using the rest resource annotation. The apex class takes the json payload, parses it, looks up a lead record from info in the payload, it then updates a field on the lead record. It sends back a response and that’s it. The endpoint right now is a public one with a shared secret key and ip whitelisting. I’m at a point where to I can access and hit the endpoint and my apex class runs. I’ve tested this in workbench and all works as expected and lead is updated correctly. I run this from cURL and I get back my custom response when a lead is not found. Same json payload provided for both examples. So obviously the lead exists. This must be some sort of permissions related issue. Hoping someone with experience in salesforce sites, it’s particular permissions around guest user access will have some insights. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing it from workbench means that you're testing the endpoint as a registered user (probably an admin). Since the endpoint is a public one, you should testing it as a guest and most likely that's the cURL test and that's why it behaves differently. If you want to be 100% sure, you could test the enpoint with Postman sending a request without the Authorization header and if you still get "lead not found" as response, it means that the guest user cannot see the record.

From Setup, search for "Sites and Domains" and click on "Sites", then on your site's name and on *Public Access Settings* button to open the Guest User profile. Be sure the guest user has read permission on Lead object and fields and can access to the apex classes involved in the process.
I prefer creating a permission set and assing it to the Guest User instead of editing the profile.

If the class is `with sharing` change it to `without sharing`. Please note that [Guest User cannot have edit permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_reduce_object_perms.htm&release=228&type=5) since Winter '21, so you should not enforce user mode on dml.

In order to share a record with a Guest User, you could also create a Lead Sharing Rule selecting **Guest user access, based on criteria** as Rule Type if there are some criteria that you could use to share just a subset of records.

Comment: thank you! it was the without sharing that fixed it!